# ScopeMismatch on using session scoped fixture with pytest-mozwebqa plugin for py.test

Tags: python, pytest, fixtures

I am using `pytest-mozwebqa` plugin for running some selenium tests. I want to login to the application only once for all the tests so I tried using a session scoped fixture in the `conftest.py` but I am getting following error. How can I write this login fixture so that login is not required per test and a single login is available to all tests?

This is the error I am getting:

```
================================================================================================= ERRORS ==================================================================================================
___________________________________________________________________________ ERROR at setup of TestData.test_selected_version ____________________________________________________________________________
ScopeMismatch: You tried to access the 'function' scoped fixture 'mozwebqa' with a 'module' scoped request object, involved factories
conftest.py:6:  def login(mozwebqa, variables)
../../.virtualenvs/webqa/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pytest_mozwebqa/pytest_mozwebqa.py:159:  def pytest_funcarg__mozwebqa(request)
```

Content of the `conftest.py`:

```
@pytest.fixture(scope='session')
def login(mozwebqa, variables):
    data_page = DataPage(mozwebqa)
    network_page = data_page.select_version(variables)
    return network_page
```

Answer (score 4):

you need to make the login function scope, same as the mozwebqa fixture

Comment: Thanks! It works if I keep login as function scope. However,  that makes login run for each test. I want to run login  only once at the start for all the tests and continue using same session. Is there a way I can achieve that?

Comment: not with the current mozwebqa, it provides only a fixture at function scope,

Comment: there is a planned feature for fixtures that may have own instances per skope, but its tricky to make it work nice (since we expect that we need to iterate on many api versions)

Comment: @Ronny I could use this feature. Is there a ticket or other reference where I can follow it?

Comment: @JasonR.CoombsTry using other plugins like [pytest-selenium](https://github.com/pytest-dev/pytest-selenium). `mozwebqa` is no longer maintained.

Comment: @JasonR.Coombs i didnt find it in a quick search, iplease open a issue elaborating your use-case, we can then eventually crosslink

Answer (score 0):

[k4nar](https://github.com/k4nar) posted this workaround [on the github issue for the bug](https://github.com/pytest-dev/pytest/issues/2704#issuecomment-603387680), and it’s working fine for me.

> ```
> @pytest.fixture(scope=session)
> def my_fixture(request):
>     capmanager = request.config.pluginmanager.getplugin("capturemanager")
>
>     ...
>
>     with capmanager.global_and_fixture_disabled():
>         print_something()
>
>     ...
> ```