# pytest: Using a "session" scope fixture along with default scope fixtures

Tags: python, scope, pytest, fixtures

I'm building a pytest test suite, testing a package I'm building. The tests should verify some things about the pkg, such as minor functionality checks, minor sanity checks and so on. Some of the checks are done pre-install and some post-install (example code):

---

Tests file:

```
import pytest

class PreInstallTests(object):
    def test_foo(self, bar):
        assert bar > 2

class PostInstallTests(object):
    def test_goo(self, baz):
        assert baz < 3

    def test_hoo(self, baz):
        assert baz > 1
```

---

conftest file:

```
import pytest
@pytest.fixture
def tmp_dir():
    os.mkdir('tmp')
    yield
    shutil.rmtree('tmp')

@pytest.fixture
def bar(tmp_dir):
    yield 3

@pytest.fixture
def baz(install, tmp_dir):
    yield 2

@pytest.fixture(scope='session')
def install():
    # installs the pkg... (takes a lot of time)
```

As can be seen here, I have 2 post-install tests, each one using a fixture called `baz` that uses the `install` fixture. I want to have only one installation, and either use the same installation for all post-install-tests (not ideal, but the tests are minimal, and I don't want to waste much time on re-installing currently).

Using the "scope" session parameter can solve my problem, but that would prohibit me from using any other fixture, such as "tmp_dir" (which represents a fixture that I need, and must stay default-scoped...)

How can I achieve one install for all tests, and still use my other fixtures, whom I want to leave with their default scope?

*I thought of making the `install` an autouse fixture, but I actually need it to be called after some of the other fixtures that are currently default scoped, and should stay that way*

Comment: _Using the "scope" session parameter can solve my problem, but that would prohibit me from using any other fixture, such as "tmp_dir"_ - you mean, prohibit using `tmp_dir` in `install`? Other than that (and wrong placed scope parameter in the `install` fixture), I don't see any issues with your code.

Comment: You can always introduce another fixture, like e.g. `real_install` which is session-scoped, and change `install` to smth like `def install(tmp_dir, real_install): return real_install` with the default function scope. This way, the installation will still run once and you can combine its result with function-scoped fixtures.

Comment: @hoefling For your 1st comment - yes, but I actually have a lot of fixtures like that one.. For your 2nd - thought about it, but that would make me change a lot of my fixtures into function calls (e.g. I have a fixture that shows the path of the pkg - so that would have to be a call to function)

Comment: @CIsForCookies, do you mean to say you want to use `tmp_dir` and many such function scoped fixtures in `install` fixture? Or you just want them be called before the `install` fixture.

Answer (score 1):

Only solution I could think of is to have a flag controlling if you've already run the installation code, then keep the fixture with default scope.

```py
import pytest

installed = False

@pytest.fixture()
def install():
    global installed
    if not installed:
        print('installing')
        installed = True
```

Comment: Fixtures should not really save the state machine. I also thought of this, but I am not going to use this, even though it solves my basic question because I don't want to go to globals

Answer (score 0):

as described in [ScopeMismatch on using session scoped fixture with pytest-mozwebqa plugin for py.test](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31500480/scopemismatch-on-using-session-scoped-fixture-with-pytest-mozwebqa-plugin-for-py?rq=1)

use the session scoped tmpdir_factory for install and remove tmp_dir, consume builtin tmpdir, since pytest 3.x.